# Base URL/Domain problem

Tags: 8, uri, migrations

I moved a Drupal site to a development domain, but for some reason none of the menu links have updated. For example, in the main menu, one of the links is www.example.com/product. I would expect it to change to www.devdomain.com/product after moving it to my dev domain, but it doesn't.

Similarly, even the links in the Seven admin theme still point to www.example.com (my live site) instead of the dev domain. So clicking "Structure", for example, tries to route me back to the live site.

Anyone ever experience this and know how to solve? There are no references to base_url in my settings.php file for this site, and I am not using the trusted host patterns setting (though I have tried with and without).

A few other things I have tried:

- running update.php
- drush cr
- searching for instances of example.com in codebase (there are none)

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out multilingual modules were on, and using URL detection. When that is set, the URL for the particular language you are looking at gets inserted into all links.